# iPhone Calendar with Week View?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, calendar

Hey, I was wondering if there's any source codes out there for an iPhone Calendar with a Week view too. 
I searched for it but I didn't have any luck. I'm working on an app what needs the the week view in the Calendar.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well then I would recommend you trying to combine these 2 source codes!

https://github.com/muhku/calendar-ui

and

http://ved-dimensions.blogspot.com/2009/04/iphone-development-creating-native_09.html

Answer (score 2):

Check out the [TapKuLibrary](https://github.com/devinross/tapkulibrary).

Answer (score 1):

The only one I am aware of, is the following one:

[calendar-ui](https://github.com/muhku/calendar-ui)

This works on iPhone/iPod, but not on the iPad (at least as is).

Answer (score 0):

There's an example in the blog post here on how to do this (complete with source code):

http://ved-dimensions.blogspot.com/2009/04/iphone-development-creating-native_09.html

Hope this helps. :)

Answer (score 0):

You could try the [CSWeekView](http://code.google.com/p/csweekview/) project. Its for Mac OS X, but it probably wouldn't be too difficult to adapt it to work on iOS.